# How to refer to a sheet within a workbook without using index number ie position of sheet in workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a Excel workbook with sheets: ***"Excel1"*** and ***"Hello1"***.The macro button in *"Excel1"* takes the value from *"Hello1"*.

When I make multiple copies of sheet,the sheet *"Excel1(k)"* must take value from *"Hello1(k)"*,similar as *"Excel1"* from *"Hello1"*.[k-Any random number assumed].I have written a code which refers to sheet using Index number but the problem is whenever i move the position of sheets the macro doesn't work as expected.

So, how can I refer to a sheet irrespective to the position of sheet position (INDEX)?

```
Sub value()
Dim shcount As Integer
Dim horzn As Integer
Dim i As Integer
i = ActiveSheet.Index / 2

With Sheets("Hello1 (" & i & ")")
      horzn = .Range("A5")
      Sheets("Excel1 (" & i & ")").Cells(3, 3).value = horzn
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand completely, but I think you can just match the part of the Excel1(k) name inside the parentheses (the "suffix") to that same part in the Hello1 name. Here's the idea (untested but compiles):

```
Sub value()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wsExcel1 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wsHello1 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim Suffix As String

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   If Left(wsExcel1.Name, 6) = "Excel1" Then
      Set wsExcel1 = ws
      Suffix = Replace(wsExcel1.Name, "Excel1", "")
      Set wsHello1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hello1" & Suffix)
      wsExcel1.Range("C3").value = wsHello1.Range("A5").value
   End If
Next
End Sub
```

Note that maybe you don't have to loop through all the sheets. If you are assuming the Activesheet is the Excel1 sheet then just `Set Excel1 = ActiveSheet` and get rid of the loop.

Comment: I got the idea!! Thanks